# Viewscoped bean doesnt retain it's state when returning to the same view?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Im currently testing on JSF Bean that make use of ViewScope

I notice this behaviour.

When having this button :

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit Data to Server" 
    ajax="false" update="debugPanel" />
```

I can see the postconstruct happens only once, and the submission triggered by this button doest trigger postconstruct, which is correct, since it's returning to the same view.

But when i add modify my button into this :

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit Data to Server" 
    ajax="false" update="debugPanel" 
    action="viewScope2.xhtml?faces-redirect=false"/>
```

I can see that the postconstruct method gets called for every submission, which means the bean doesnt retain it's state, although it's actualy returning to the same view. I thought this is because of the redirectin, so i omitted it, and the button becomes something like this :

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit Data to Server" 
    ajax="false" update="debugPanel" 
    action="viewScope2.xhtml"/>
```

But still, the postconstruct method gets called for every submission, which is not desireable.

Is it possible to have this idealism :

> No matter whether it's explicitly or
>   implicily defined (via attribute or
>   via return "myview.xhtml" in action
>   method) , whether it's using redirect
>   or not, the viewscoped bean will
>   always retain it's state when
>   returning to the same view.

Please share your opinions !

Thank you .....

Comment: Did you implement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416070/jsf-2-and-post-redirect-get ? That can be the cause.

Comment: @BalusC: No, i did not in this case. Since without explicitly stating the target view, it still works fine, which is the first case in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically all these questions have been answered in this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494950/jsf-2-viewscope-questions) .. Thank you !