# JSF 2 ViewScope questions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Quoting from this [nice article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html),

> The new view scope should solve
>   exactly those issues. A @ViewScoped
>   bean will live as long as you're
>   submitting the form to the same view
>   again and again. In other words, as
>   long as when the action method(s)
>   returns null or even void, the bean
>   will be there in the next request.
>   Once you navigate to a different view,
>   then the bean will be trashed.

And these questions come into mind:

1. If my current view is `index.xhtml`, and if I specify explicitly `return "index";` or `<h:commandButton action="index.xhtml" ..>`, which is basically returning to the same view, the bean will be recreated again .. why?
2. Can a viewscoped bean survive a redirection?
3. And if it can, how can I specify it? I can't imagine doing something like `return "?faces-redirect=true"` or `<h:commandButton action="?faces-redirect=true" ..>`, and yes, I would like to skip defining the navigation in `faces-config.xml` using the `<redirect/>`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265433/how-and-when-is-a-view-scope-bean-destroyed-in-jsf/15391453#15391453) to the question *"How and when is a view scope bean destroyed in JSF?"* might be relevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *If my current view is index.xhtml, and if i specify explicitly return "index"; or , which is basically returning to the same view, the bean will be recreated again .. why ?*

If you explicitly specify an outcome (read: a view), then a new view will be created. You have to return null or void from the action method (or just leave out the `action` attribute of the command component).

I must admit that I understand your confusion and that the term "view" can be interpreted differently, depending on the context. I think I'll revise the wording in the linked article sooner or later.

> *Can a Viewscoped bean survive a redirection ?*

No. Only session scoped beans can and objects in the [flash scope](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html) also (which ends immediately once the redirect has been finished, that's maybe which you *actually* need for the functional requirement you had in mind when asking this question).

Answer (score 0):

The view state can survive redirection if the javax.faces.ViewState is supplied. The currently most simple solution I found, is implementing a navigation handler.

In faces-config.xml:

```
<faces-config>
    <application>
        ...
        <navigation-handler>com.intersult.jsf.util.RedirectNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
    </application>
    ...
</faces-config>
```

The Java class:

```
public class RedirectNavigationHandler extends ConfigurableNavigationHandler {
    private NavigationHandler parent;

    public RedirectNavigationHandler(NavigationHandler parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleNavigation(FacesContext context, String from, String outcome) {
        if (!context.getPartialViewContext().isPartialRequest()) {
            if (outcome == null)
                outcome = context.getViewRoot().getViewId();
            if (!outcome.endsWith("?faces-redirect=true"))
                outcome += "?faces-redirect=true";
            String viewState =
                context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(ResponseStateManager.VIEW_STATE_PARAM);
            outcome += "&javax.faces.ViewState=" + viewState;
        }
        parent.handleNavigation(context, from, outcome);
    }
}
```

This has some impact: Each redirect is not an independent request anymore. It depends on the view state, which can not neccesarily be restored. So have a fallback strategy, if it is expired eg. redirect on view expired exception.