# JSF 2.0: POST/Redirect/GET pattern when action method return null (stay on the same page)

Tags: jsf-2

I need to avoid double POST on refresh. So I'm using [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern (`faces-redirect=true`) and navigation handler (by @BalusC) like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416070/jsf-2-and-post-redirect-get). How to use that pattern in JSF 2.0 when action method return `null` (stay on the same page) ? Is it even possible or i need to use something other that POST/Redirect/GET ? I need to keep alive a view-scoped bean, so returning in action method the same view (PRG works) is not a solution (causes lost `view scope`).

view test.xhtml:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.send}"/>
```

bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
class Bean {
   String send() {
       // do something...
       return null;
   }

   String send2() {
       // do something...
       return "test";  // view scope lost
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you give an example of the case of use that you are trying to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Marioosh.

Post/Redirect/Get causes two lifecycle scenarios:

- The redirect causes a Non-Faces Response (Section 2.1 of the JSF-2 spec).
- Get causes a Non-faces request with a Faces Response (Section 2.1.1). A new view is created in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

some frameworks do implement this strategy by default: for example Spring WebFlow. Each Submit (POST) is followed by a redirect GET with a parameter "execution" enabling Spring to find the SAME view. 
for example :

```
http://myhost:8080/booking-spring-faces/spring/mypage?execution=e1s2
```

I would love to find this feature in JSF toolkits like Omnifaces from BalusC !