# Automatically include view parameters in URL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, post-redirect-get, viewparams

I have simple jsf page with view params and load method which is processing those params:

```
<f:metadata>
 <f:viewParam name="param1" value="#{bean.param1}"/>
 <f:viewParam name="param2" value="#{bean.param2}"/>
 <f:viewParam name="param3" value="#{bean.param3}"/>
 <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.load()}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

I also set some initial values in `@PostConstruct`.
How to redirect user to new location that include those parameters (which are not null).
For example user enter in browser:

```
domain.com/page.jsf
```

and is redirected to:

```
domain.com/page.jsf?param1=valueA
```

because param1 was set in `@PostConstruct`.

Another question - I have links on page referencing same view:

```
<h:link value="clickme">
 <f:param name="param3" value="otherValue"/>
</h:link>
```

When user enters page with `?param1=someValue` and clicks link, got redirected to `?param3=otherValue` but I want to redirect to `?param1=someValue&param3=otherValue`.
I know I can add more parameters in `<h:link>` but it's diffucult to add every possible param in every `<h:link>`

PS. I use BalusC tip from this topic [JSF 2 and Post/Redirect/Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416070/jsf-2-and-post-redirect-get)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As to the 1st question: you can add `includeViewParams=true` to the navigation case outcome. But you can never guarantee that you'll sucessfully be redirected while you're doing that inside a `preRenderView` method. It might be already too late then.

As to the 2nd question: you can set the `includeViewParams` attribute of `<h:link>` to `true`.

```
<h:link value="clickme" includeViewParams="true">
    <f:param name="param3" value="otherValue"/>
</h:link>
```

Alternatively, you can also add `includeViewParams=true` to the outcome.

```
<h:link value="clickme" outcome="otherPage?includeViewParams=true">
    <f:param name="param3" value="otherValue"/>
</h:link>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I use your tip from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416070/jsf-2-and-post-redirect-get/5419730#5419730, I also added `outcome += "&includeViewParams=true";` in `handleNavigation()`, but I'll try use `includeViewParams` at `h:link`

Comment: As to 1st question: user enters `page.jsf` explicitly in browser, not using any link, is it possible to redirect in this case?

Comment: OK,`includeViewParams` inside `h:link` helped (wonder why doing this in `handleNavigation()` dosen't work), 1st question is still open

Comment: does the bean need to to use @Inject?

Comment: @thufir: no, it serves a completely different purpose.