# JSF - Function creating request param String?

Tags: jsf, http-request-parameters

Is there a function that creates a request param String using the current request params `#{params}` or internal `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()`?

Example:

Website is opened with following url: `index.xhtml?lang=en&q=test`

A dynamic link on the site could access specific keys from the `params` map but all 'unknown' keys should be used like:

Link jsf: `index.xhtml?#{mapToString(param)}`

Output: `index.xhtml?lang=en&q=test`

Function:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/two-ways-convert-java-map

Or is this a candidate for omnifaces BalusC?

Comment: Set includeViewParams=true in <h:link>, that way you can carry the view parameters from one page to another, See BalusC's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257112/jsf-2-0-automatically-include-view-parameters-in-url)

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was searching for