# Get data of View Scoped Bean in another page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have 2 pages. The page 1 will transfer some data into page 2 so i have to use session scoped for bean in page 1. In page 2, i have to change some data which will influence data in page 1. But i go back page 1, the data is still not change. If i use View scope in page 1 i cannot transfer into page 2. Pls help me do

Comment: [JSF 2.0 - automatically include view parameters in url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7257414/1065197)

Comment: How are you "going back" to page 1 and what browser are you using? If you are trying to use the browser back button that isn't going to work because the browser is going to display the page from cache.