# How to cancel form without validation phase in JSF?

Tags: validation, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I have `xhtml` form with two buttons: "OK" and "Cancel". Both buttons calls methods of `@ViewScoped` managed bean (accept() and cancel(), for example).
Moreover, `xhtml` has `viewParam` and some validation.

In the `managedBean` state controlled by boolean variable `edit`. Method `cancel` turns `edit` variable to `false`.

The question is: how can I call `cancel()` method of `managedBean` without validation step? Say, I pressed "New record" button and change my mind. Now I want to cancel edit operation and when I push "Cancel" button - validation error appears, but managedBean changes state to browse (variable `edit` turns to `false`). The only I need - is to hide validation error message, or skip validation phase during POST request. If I use GET request, I am afraid that `viewParam` get lost, because view will be updated.

Is any way to skip validation phase in JSF?

Thank you for wasting your time.

Comment: Maybe you want to use the `immediate` attribute? http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-txWIIU0O_vM/Ujk6Hu2mYmI/AAAAAAAAAEI/ocaRisuNkv8/s1600/JSf+LifeCycle.png. Note that, IIRC, the values **are** applied, so in the HTML form you will see the values that you wrote (if you wrote `foo` in a date field, no error will be raised but you will have `foo` again written in that field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If I use GET request, I am afraid that viewParam get lost, because view will be updated.*

Performing a full page refresh using GET is the right way (provided that you've a `@ViewScoped` bean). To cover the mentioned problem, just tell `<h:link>` or `<h:button>` in question to include view params.

```
<h:button value="Cancel" includeViewParams="true" />
```

#### See also:

- [Reset input fields without executing validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619228/reset-input-fields-without-executing-validation)
- [Automatically include view parameters in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257112/jsf-2-0-automatically-include-view-parameters-in-url/)

Comment: So, I can use only `includeViewParams = "true"` instead of adding params to `outcome` parameter of `<h:button>`? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Outcome defaults to current view. I gathered that just the current view needs to be refreshed by GET.

Comment: Thank you very much. You JSF guru!