# Duplicate form submission in JSF form

Tags: jsf-2

I have developed a form with jsf 2. When I am pressing on Submit button, it is working fine. But problem is, when I refresh the browser, the form is submitting again, without giving any waring or message. Please, help me to sove this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF 2 and Post/Redirect/Get?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416070/jsf-2-and-post-redirect-get)

Answer (score 0):

Put a redirect in your submit handler. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get