# How to access the navigation-case of the faces config from a Java class

Tags: jsf-2, faces-config, facescontext

I have this situation, where I have to access the entire faces config from a managed beans. More specifically, I need to access the list of navigation cases, that were specified in the faces-config and cycle through them.
Is there any way to get them?

I saw that [NavigationCase](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationCase.html) has some good methods that reveal some useful information .. Question is now, how to get a list of these NavigationCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Tags you have specified in your question, i can say that you are using JSF 2, so you can use the `ConfigurableNavigationHandler` to get what you are looking for.

Use the `ConfigurableNavigationHandler#getNavigationCases()` to get a `Map` of Navigation cases, you can get more informations about that method from it's [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ConfigurableNavigationHandler.html#getNavigationCases()):

> Return a `Map<String, Set<NavigationCase>>` where the keys are
>    values and the values are Set where
>   each element in the Set is a NavigationCase that applies to that
>   .

This is an example for invoking that method:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ConfigurableNavigationHandler navigationHandler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
Map<String,Set<NavigationCase>> navigationCases = navigationHandler.getNavigationCases();
```

In case you already knew the name of the page you want to navigate to, you can simply use that example (assuming your page file is next.xhtml):

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ConfigurableNavigationHandler navigationHandler= (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
navigationHandler.performNavigation("next");
```

**See also:**

- [JSF 2 and Post/Redirect/Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419730/4170582)
- [Java Code Examples for javax.faces.application.ConfigurableNavigationHandle](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.faces.application.ConfigurableNavigationHandler)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
FacesContext ctxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ConfigurableNavigationHandler configNavHandler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)ctxt.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
NavigationCase navCase = configNavHandler.getNavigationCase(ctxt,null,"Page");
String toViewId = navCase.getToViewId(ctxt);
```